# Handle raw PNG data received from api in JavaScript, jQuery or AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, png

I am getting this from the api:

[image: PNG data]

Not sure exactly what type of format this is, but it is cleary a PNG. With Curl you can do this:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer GX6OONHlQ9qoVaCSmBqJvqPFUT5i" -X GET \
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/thumbnails/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bXlidWNrZXQvc2t5c2NwcjEuM2Rz  > C:\Users\Public\thumb.png
```

But I am using AngularJS and what to display the image in HTML. I tried using FileReader:

```
    function thumbnailReceived(png) {

        console.log(png);

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        // convert to file
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(png)

        // save result 
        var file = fileReader.result

        console.log(file);

        return file;
    }
```

But this just gave me the error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
    at TypeError (native)
    at thumbnailReceived (http://localhost:13872/app/autodesk/js/services/AutodeskAPIService.js:23:24)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:119:129
    at r.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:133:313)
    at r.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:130:412)
    at r.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:134:78)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:87:444)
    at T (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:92:50)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:93:78)
```

How can I convert this data and display it with html? Using a javascript library? angularJS function? Convert to base64 and put it directly in a html `img.src` attribute?

Comment: Do you have the correct headers set on your response that brings the image back?

Comment: Didn't set any headers, but I do get Content-Type:image/png in the response

Comment: Why can't you just set the image `src` attribute to the request url? Also, you need to create a [`blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) from the response then pass it to the function [`readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer).

Comment: why not use an `<img>`-tag with [ng-Src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)?

Comment: Putting the data directly into the img.src tag does not work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?